# Getting Audio Stream Using Socket Connection

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8, audio-streaming, icecast

I am new to socket programming, and would like to develop an radio streaming app using socket connection.

The URI of the stream is something like http://abc11.abcradio.com:8256/stream

Setting the hostname to abc11.abcradio.com and the port to 8256, and using the following code:

```
private async void Connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if (connected)
     {
         StatusText.Text = "Already connected";
         return;
     }

     try
     {
            OutputView.Text = "";
            StatusText.Text = "Trying to connect ...";

            serverHost = new HostName(ServerHostname.Text);
            // Try to connect to the 
            await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, ServerPort.Text);
            connected = true;
            StatusText.Text = "Connection established" + Environment.NewLine;

            dataReader = new DataReader(clientSocket.InputStream);

            string receivedString = String.Empty;
            uint numBytesRead;

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    numBytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(128);

                    StatusText.Text += numBytesRead.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // something went wrong in the socket connection
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If this is an unknown status, 
            // it means that the error is fatal and retry will likely fail.
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }

            StatusText.Text = "Connect failed with error: " + exception.Message;
            // Could retry the connection, but for this simple example
            // just close the socket.

            closing = true;
            // the Close method is mapped to the C# Dispose
            clientSocket.Dispose();
            clientSocket = null;

        }
    }

}
```

I am getting 0's.

abc11.abcradio.com:8256 returns a page with the stream info in the browser, and abc11.abcradio.com:8256/stream opens a page playing the stream.

How can I get the stream data?

Comment: That link is dead, but why aren't you using an HTTP client for this?  And, I don't see where you're making an HTTP request in this code.

Comment: The link was only for example, not an actual one. 

I thought that connecting directly via socket would be faster...?

Comment: I imagine a built-in HTTP client will be much faster than rolling your own.  It wouldn't matter either way though since the bottleneck will be in network and the server sending you data.

Comment: I connected to the URI using built-in HTTP client, but I also would like to know how to connect and get the audio data from the Icecast server...

Comment: Yes, you should be able to connect and stream the response.

Comment: I know, but I could not :) What might be wrong with the code above, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry no, I haven't done any C# in years.  I would suggest going the HTTP route and asking about how to stream data with the standard HTTP client.  That's a method that applies to almost anyone using the HTTP client, so there will be much broader knowledge of it.  Plus, you don't want to have to maintain your own HTTP client.  What will you do in the code above if the response is a redirect?  Have you read all of RFC2616 and related, and implemented what you need?  There's a lot to it.

Comment: OK, thank you commenting on this...